# Google map default marker icon+label does not match maps.google.com style

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to set a marker icon+label in a google map so that it matches exactly the same CSS style that maps.google.com uses?

Comment: The default is the same.

Comment: @JohnM when i add a marker it shows with a black label and without the circle at the bottom of the balloon